# C++ Executable distribution strategy

Tags: c++, linux, distribution

Recently I have asked a question about what I should use to [create self-contained executables that would be deployed under a number of Linux distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416339/linux-stand-alone-executable-generation). I got very scared at first, but after reading about C++ a little, I managed to get the first version of my executable going.

After a day full of joy, I just hit the wall again with another dilemma. The resulting executable must be installed in a number of Linux distributions (Slackware, Arch, Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS and a few more), and I am completely clueless on how to achieve it. All I know CentOS and Debian-based OSes has package managers, like apt or yum, but I am not sure those apply to my case.

The code I wrote depends on a couple of libraries (more specifically [RudeSocket](http://rudeserver.com/socket/install.html) and [yaml-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/). I have been told that I would be able to compile the executable and link it dynamically, so I just needed to distribute the executable.

It happens that I could not find the .a file for the yaml-cpp library (just for RudeSocket). And here's my problem so far:

At first, I went with dynamic linking but (obviously) when I copied the executable to another box:

```
$ ./main
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libyaml-cpp.so.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When trying to compile it statically, I get an error too (because I don't have the yaml-cpp .a file as I mentioned):

```
$ g++ main.cpp parse.cpp parse.h rudesocket-1.3.0/.libs/librudesocket.a -o main -static -L/usr/local/librudesocket-1.3.0/.libs/librudesocket.a(socket_connect_normal.o): In function `rude::sckt::Socket_Connect_Normal::simpleConnect(int&, char const*, int)':
/root/webbyget/sockets/rudesocket-1.3.0/src/socket_connect_normal.cpp:250: warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/tmp/cc3cEVK1.o: In function `operator>>(YAML::Node const&, Job&)':
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1a83): undefined reference to `YAML::Node::size() const'
/tmp/cc3cEVK1.o: In function `handle_job(rude::Socket, char const*)':
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1b79): undefined reference to `YAML::Parser::Parser(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1bfd): undefined reference to `YAML::Node::Node()'
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1c10): undefined reference to `YAML::Parser::GetNextDocument(YAML::Node&)'
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1dc6): undefined reference to `YAML::Node::size() const'
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1dee): undefined reference to `YAML::Node::~Node()'
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1e18): undefined reference to `YAML::Node::~Node()'
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1e37): undefined reference to `YAML::Parser::~Parser()'
parse.cpp:(.text+0x1e61): undefined reference to `YAML::Parser::~Parser()'
(...)
```

It's pretty obvious to me that g++ cannot compile it statically without telling it where to find the classes for yaml-cpp.

It is very important that the installation should happen without human interaction, in an automated fashion.

So my question is really twofold:

- how can I distribute this compiled program in the least complex way targeting all those distributions?
- is there any de facto standard solution for this kind of problem?

Thank you in advance,

Felipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might give [this technique](http://blog.linuxgamepublishing.com/2009/02/08/our-new-way-to-meet-the-lgpl/) a try.

Comment: This looks like a very good option.  Basically, you dynamically link, but use a special -rpath option to force the run-time linker to look for the libs in the same directory as the executable.  Then you distributed the dynamic libraries with the executable.

Comment: This is a good technique but I ended up acquiring a copy of [Ermine](http://www.magicermine.com/). So worth it :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are many de-facto standards, but none of them are standardized. :(  If you want to distribute a compiled binary, you will probably want to make a package for each platform you want to target.  Generating an rpm and a deb will probably get you 90% of the way.  If you want to automate the build process, autoconf/automake is still (probably) the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the platforms package manager (.rpm or .deb) the system will check for the correct version of the shared library for you and download it if it is needed.

[CPack](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:Packaging_With_CPack) is probably the easiest package generator

Answer (score 0):

Maybe The best solution for you is to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).

[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) is cross-platform, open-source build system. It is a family of tools designed to build, test and package software. For Packaging, Mgb is right, CMake can easily be coupled with [CPack](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Packaging_With_CPack).

KDE is using this solution and its a very good alternative to automake/autoconf.